# What size connection do I need for this gas dryer hose?

Tags: dryer, gas, connectors, adapter

Could you please tell me what size I need for this gas dryer hose?

https://ibb.co/BzxSNtG
https://ibb.co/3WnYrBm
https://ibb.co/9nkjTGq

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll please use the site's built in image hosting, the images can be directly embedded into the question without your readers having to click links to external sites. Simply [edit] your question then either drag the images into the edit box or click the "sun & mountain" icon above the edit box and paste the links in there.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're referring to the brass connector fully shown in the pictures and not the dryer vent hose shown partially off-screen, the pictures don't give enough scale to tell the exact size of connector needed.

This a gas connection. Hardware stores have gas connection kits with appropriate adapters to connect the dryer to typical gas supplies.

Gas connections are very dangerous if not done exactly right. Leaks can kill everyone in the house either through asphyxiation because no one recognized that strange smell, or explosions. Based on your needing to inquire what size to use instead of knowing what to do, I deduce that you may not have the skills to diy this safely. Get a plumber to make this connection.

Comment: `Based on your needing to inquire what size to use instead of knowing what to do, I deduce that you may not have the skills to diy this safely. Get a plumber to make this connection.` +1000!